# What's a good linux tool for converting MKV files to AVI?

Tags: linux, avi, matroska

Preferably something that works on Fedora.

Answer (score 2):

Enable [RPMFusion](http://rpmfusion.org/), then:

```
yum install avidemux-gtk
```

or

```
yum install avidemux-qt
```